# php GD captcha image not showing on Mac

Tags: php, macos, gd, captcha

I'm using a simple captcha system for a form. Works fine on Windows but it not showing on Mac. In both systems DG is enabled, I've checked with phpinfo().

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // generate random number and store in session

    $randomnr = rand(1000, 9999);
    $_SESSION['randomnr2'] = md5($randomnr);

    //generate image
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(90, 32);

    //colors:
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 200, 35, $black);

    //path to font:

    $font = 'fonts/rock-webfont.ttf';

    //draw text:
    //imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 22, 24, $grey, $font, $randomnr);
    //imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 15, 26, $white, $font, $randomnr);
        imagettftext($im, 24, 0, 12, 26, $grey, $font, $randomnr);
    imagettftext($im, 24, 0, 8, 28, $white, $font, $randomnr);

    // prevent client side  caching
    header("Expires: Wed, 1 Jan 1997 00:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    //send image to browser
    header ("Content-type: image/gif");
    imagegif($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

UPDATE: I'm using OS X Snow Leopard with PHP Version 5.3.3 installed. I now enabled error reporting and I see this error: Call to undefined function imagettftext(). This is strange because if I navigate to the definition of the function it takes me to the imagettftext() in the GD library!

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Mauro

Comment: Add error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On'); at the beginning of your php script to see possible errors. I see two possible problems: it cannot find the font-file or the header stuff makes problems on windows

Comment: What do you mean "on Mac"? On a Mac server? On a mac browser? What happens if you try to access the CAPTCHA image directly, what message do you get?

Comment: @strauberry I added the error reporting and I got this: Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext() in /Users/.../captcha.php on line 26. What kind of error is? how do I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the error is `Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext()` it means the GD module is not installed.

By the way, please update your question clarifying what and where you're trying to do. What does "on a Mac" means? Which operating system are you using? Which web sever? Which version? Which PHP version? And so on...

Comment: This is strange because if I navigate to the definition of the function it takes me to the imagettftext() in the GD library!

Comment: You "navigate"? How? Where? In your IDE? Your IDE is not the web server, If you see something in your IDE it doesn't mean it available on the web server too. BTW, you missed to specify which web server (and version) you're using.

Comment: yes im my ide. But I've run phpinfo and shows that gd is installed:

Comment: That's the GD enabled from phpinfo():

Comment: GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
GIF Read Support  enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support  enabled
libJPEG Version  8
PNG Support  enabled
libPNG Version  1.4.3
WBMP Support  enabled
XBM Support  enabled

Comment: Is the `phpinfo()` page in the same virtual host as the page experiencing the error? Maybe the extension is enabled on a single virtual host. If you try to implement the example shown [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) in a new page it works?

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3.x on Snow Leopard is missing the ttf (TrueType) module